# How to mix overflow:auto with position:absolute

Tags: html, css

Given a parent with overflow:auto (required to fix a margin issue), is it possible to place a child element with position absolute outside the parent.

HTML

```
<div class="second"><p>Second</p><span>X</span></div>
```

CSS

```
div { border: 1px #000 solid;}
.second { overflow: auto; position:relative;}
span {position:absolute; top:0; left:-5px;}
```

Problem : I see only half of the 'X' character, but i want to see the full character.

cf http://jsfiddle.net/p69nzmv7/

Comment: It is possible. What result would you expect? By moving the span 5 pixels to the left the result looks correct to me.

Comment: [`overflow:visible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) might be more appropriate. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/p69nzmv7/1/).

Comment: do you need X outside the div? If so then you don't need to define overflow property. by making it left:5px instead of -5px i can see it correct.

Comment: Note that "visible" is the default value if [`overflow` is not specified](http://jsfiddle.net/p69nzmv7/2/).

Comment: that's because you have `left:-5px`. Change it to 5px and it will work